# Using rosjava, I can subscribe but not publish to rostopics on separate machines

Tags: ros, subscribe, rosjava, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pretty simple, as the name implies, I can't publish messages from rosjava over the network.

The Java side of things is a GUI that subscribes to a few topics (a video stream and some Float64's) with the ability to send input-based commands by publishing to topics. The rosjava node works as expected when run locally to the topics; I can both publish and subscribe.  But when the rosjava node is run from a machine separate to the one running the topics that I wish to publish to, it doesn't work.  The publishers seem to get registered correctly based on the output going to my console, and the subscribers work as I receive both video and data, but when I trigger an input that would attempt to publish a command there is no effect on the other end.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58036/using-rosjava,-i-can-subscribe-but-not-publish-to-rostopics-on-separate-machines/) by [dljsjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4417/dljsjr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that it was an issue with our network and hostname resolution.  Setting ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME on both ends fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [dljsjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4417/dljsjr/) with karma: 51 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0